# Unable to merge a branch to master, due to tree conflicts

Tags: xcode

I was on a branch and a done with the work on that branch. So switched back to master. Now am trying to merge the branch that I worked on to MASTER. It's showing the following error.

This is the error shown:

[image: this is the error shown]

Is it the right of branch usage? What is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after pulling some hairs. Fixed the issue.

1.Right Click on your project file and click on show package contents. 
2.Now go to the path that Xcode shows you.
3.Delete those files.
4.Now, merge will work fine.

Its the Xcode data created on the mac based on the Mac. The previous version (branch) might have the different one. That's the reason for the error.

Comment: What about your deleted files to be remain deleted or added afterward